# подключение header и footer в отдельном файле

Tags: html, css

Я вынес header и footer в отдельные файлы, но они не отображаются, может кто подскажет, что я не так делаю?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Главная</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="allwrapper">
        <!--#include file="header.html" -->
        <div class="middle">


            </div>
            <!--#include file="footer.html" -->
            </div>
        </body>   
        </html>
```

Comment: А у вас есть что-нибудь, что могло бы обработать эти комментарии? В чистом HTML они ничего не значат и ничего не делают.

Comment: файл то `.shtml`?

Comment: А у вас чисто HTML файл или есть серверная сторона, платформа?

Comment: Есть удаленный сервер

Comment: какой именно сервер, кэп! апач, иис, или что?

Comment: файл .htaccess по идее должен обрабатывать комментарии

Comment: Надо прописать в тегах вопроса технологию сервера, так как на чистом HTML такое не делается, только на серверной стороне, в зависимости от технологии.

Comment: Файл .htaccess ничего не обрабатывает, он только содержит часть конфигурации сервера. А сервер ещё должен поддерживать .htaccess, а вы не хотите говорить, какой у вас сервер

Comment: извините за такой вопрос, но как узнать какой сервер?

Comment: @aquido так кто кроме вас знает какой у вас серверный язык, платформа... возможно вам поможет перечисление основных: php, asp.net, jsp, nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустил через OpenServer и все стало работать, всем спасибо и извините за такие глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас главный файл называется, например, **main.shtml** ?
Тогда попробуйте так подключать :

```
    <!--#include virtual="/.../header.html" -->
    <!--#include virtual="/.../footer.html" -->
```